# Find the value of $\int_5^{15}f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=f(x+5)$, $\int_1^{5}f(x)\,dx=3$, and $\int_{-5}^{-4}f(x)\,dx=2$. Find the value of $\int_5^{15}f(x) dx$.

(A)2 (B)4 (C)6 (D)8 (E)10

I have two different answers but I don't know which one is the right one.

Solution 1:

Because of $f(x)=f(x+5)$ :

$\int_1^{5}f(x)\,dx=3$ then $\int_{-5}^{-4}f(x+5)\,dx=2$.

Let $u=x+5$ and we got $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=2$.

Using properties of definite integral:

$\int_0^{5}f(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx+\int_1^{5}f(x)\,dx=5$

From that, I know that  has period 5.

$\int_5^{15}f(x)\,dx=\int_{5}^{10}f(x)\,dx+\int_{10}^{15}f(x)\,dx=10(E)$

Solution 2:

Because the function is repeating:

$f(x)=f(x+5)=f(x+10)=f(x+15)=...$

Then :

$F(15)-F(11)=3...(1)\\F(10)-F(6)=3...(2)\\F(6)-F(5)=-2...(6)$

Using properties of integral:

$\int_5^{15}f(x)\,dx\\
=\int_{5}^{6}f(x)\,dx+\int_{6}^{10}f(x)\,dx+\int_{10}^{15}f(x)\,dx\\
=F(6)-F(5)+F(10)-F(6)+F(15)-F(10)\\
=-2+3+3\\
=4(B)$

My question is which one is right and why the other solution is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Almost there...what happened to $F(11)-F(10)$?

Comment: take $u=x+15$ and evaluate the limit values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(15)-F(10)$ is not equal to $3$. It is $F(15)-F(11)$ that is equal to $3$.

By the way, your "every 6 intervals" is confusing (or confused). $f$ has period $5$, not $6$.

Answer (score 0):

The partitions should be like,
$F(15)-F(11),F(11)-F(10),F(10)-F(6),F(6)-F(5)=3+2+3+2=10$

Comment: No, this is wrong. For instance, $F(15)-F(14)$ could take any value at all.

Comment: It is fixed now